# NSXMLParser always return error : NSXMLParserErrorDomain 4

Tags: objective-c, xml, xml-parsing, plist, nsxmlparser

I'm working on NSXMLParser to parse the chat log of Messages in Mountain Lion. The file has an extension of .ichat ...

Here are my codes

```
- (void) doParse:(NSData *)data {

NSString *dString;
UtilClass *Debug = [[UtilClass alloc] init];

/*
NSString *dictionaryString = [data description];
dString = dictionaryString;
[Debug debugLog:dString];
*/

dString = @"xmlparser: 10 \n";
[Debug debugLog:dString];

// create and init NSXMLParser object
NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

// create and init our delegate
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

// set delegate
[nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser];

// parsing...
BOOL success = [nsXmlParser parse];

// test the result
if (success) {

    dString = @"xmlparser: YES \n";
    [Debug debugLog:dString];
    // get array of users here
    //  NSMutableArray *users = [parser users];
} else {
    NSError *error2 = [nsXmlParser parserError];
    dString = @"xmlparser: ERROR :: ";
    dString = [dString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n",error2];

    [Debug debugLog:dString];

    dString = @"xmlparser: NO \n";
    [Debug debugLog:dString];
}

[parser release];
[nsXmlParser release];
```

}

Here is how the NSData is created and sent to the method above

```
NSString *logPath = @"~/Library/Messages/Archive/2012-09-06/anything on 2012-09-06 at 10.45.ichat";

    NSData *testData = [[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[logPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath]]autorelease];

            [self doParse:testData];
```

In the end , I always received 'NSXMLParserErrorDomain 4' which means that the parser is given an empty document.
However, I've log the 'data' variable just before its passed t0 the parser and the data seems fine.
What could be the problem here?

The first few lines of the XML document

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>$archiver</key>
    <string>NSKeyedArchiver</string>
    <key>$objects</key>
    <array>
        <string>$null</string>
        <dict>
```

Comment: how data in nsxmlparser was created? show  some code:

Comment: updated the post with how the nsdata is created..